# Consulta oracle agrupar

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

Alumnos

```
id   nombre
 1   Lucas
```

Examenes

```
id  fecha       nota  alumno_id
 1  25/11/2018   5       1
 2  26/11/2018   8       1
```

Necesito con una consulta, extraer la ultimo nota del alumno segun su fecha, he intentado:

```
select alumno_ID , MAX(fecha) from examenes 
where alumno_ID = (select id from alumnos) 
GROUP BY alumno_ID ;
```

Esto me trae un registro pero necesito tb el id de la tabla examen, lo que necesito es extraear de todos los alumnos cual es su ultimo examen segun la fecha que hay en la tabla examen

Comment: mmm.. podrias explicar ese query?? ese where es rarisimo, no tiene sentido.. y que pasa si agregal el id del examen al group?

Comment: no se si me he explicado mejor ahora

Comment: explicame que es ese where..

Comment: es la relacion entre alumno y examen

Comment: pero si no unes alumno con examen nunca? te voy a poner una respuesta, pero ese where no tiene ningun sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver la consulta, solo tenes que juntar tu resultado actual, devuelta con la tabla, uniendolo por fecha y alumno.

Entonces te quedaria algo de la siguiente forma

```
select a.alumno_ID, a.max_fecha, b.id 
from (
    select alumno_ID , MAX(fecha) max_fecha
    from examenes 
    where alumno_ID = (select id from alumnos) 
    GROUP BY alumno_ID) a inner join examenes b
        on a.max_fecha= b.fecha and a.alumno_ID = b.alumno_ID
```

Ahora, sigo insistiendo que ese where no tiene ningun sentido por ningun lado.

Yo probaria el siguiente query, que te va a traer exactamente el mismo resultado.

```
select a.alumno_ID, a.max_fecha, b.id 
    from (
        select alumno_ID , MAX(fecha) max_fecha
        from examenes 
        GROUP BY alumno_ID) a inner join examenes b
            on a.max_fecha= b.fecha and a.alumno_ID = b.alumno_ID
```

Es mas, si lo piensas, ese query solo funciona si la tabla alumnos tiene un solo registro, porque no podes igualar un dato de una tabla a la respuesta de otro select si esta trae mas de un registro (lo podes hacer con un IN).

Comment: algo estare haciendo mal que estoy cogiendo este error ORA-00904: "A"."fecha": invalid identifier

Comment: ejecutando solo esto si funciona: select alumno_ID , MAX(fecha) "fecha"
        from examenes 
        GROUP BY alumno_ID

Comment: supongamos que pongo : select alumno_ID , MAX(fecha) "dateCreation"
        from examenes 
        GROUP BY alumno_ID, tengo que poner on.dateCreation = b.fecha?

Comment: lo habia probado pero tengo el error aun:
-Funciona: 
select alumno_ID , MAX(fecha) "max_fecha"
        from examenes 
        GROUP BY alumno_ID
-No funciona: toda la consulta => "a"."MAX_FECHA": invalid identifier

Comment: si incluso renombre la letra a por otra, realmente tu consulta la adapto a la verdadera table y campos, tb comentarte si quito todo lo relacionado con fecha funciona, es decir. a.max_fecha

Comment: ahora si funciona, justo antes de tu solucion probe poniendo entre comillas pero en mayuscula tb funciona, esto es valido tb para sql server?

Comment: ok perfecto gracias